# Querying grandchild properties in Firebase

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to come up with a Firebase realtime DB structure for an online store.
The store should have a collection of products, each product can belong to one or more categories. Is it possible to construct a query to get all products in the `computers` category with a single HTTP request (assuming I use Firebase REST API)? Here is a sample piece of data:

```
{
  "products": {
    "-KaXxv2xD9WaIqHMsHYM": {
      "title": "Item 1",
      "categories": {
        "electronics": true,
        "computers": true
      }
    },
    "-KaXyvdw5gmuBmGi5unb": {
      "title": "Item 2",
      "categories": {
        "electronics": true
      }
    },
    "-KaXyyyzmP9Y6askhLdx": {
      "title": "Item 3",
      "categories": {
        "computers": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was also trying to use arrays for `categories` but looks like arrays support is very limited in Firebase and they should be avoided.

**UPDATE:**

This query works:

```
GET /products.json?orderBy="categories/computers"&equalTo=true
```

But it requires an index for every single category:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "products": {
      ".indexOn": ["categories/computers", "categories/electronics"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an additional `categories` node which have `products` list. That would make easier and efficient access to products for a specific category.

Similar aproach is used at Firebse sample. [See code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/NewPostActivity.java)

```
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);
```

They have save same data at `posts` and `user-posts` nodes.

Comment: I was thinking about a separate `categories` node, but it will keep only categories to product IDs mapping, this means if I want to display a page with top 50 products in a category I'll need to make 51 HTTP request.

Comment: Actually you should better keep full product information under categories node. That's also shown at Firebase samples for a similar case of yours. I've edited my answer. But please wait for other answers because I really wonder the solutions.

Comment: I see, thank you. This is unfortunate, keeping all the places in sync sucks. Whenever I update a product description I need to go through all its categories and fix it there. I don't expect sophisticated querying capabilities from a NoSQL data store, but Firebase looks too limiting in this regard.